# How to remove specific style properties of the style attribute of a domElement?

Tags: php, recursion, domdocument

I have a DomElement in PHP. I want to remove some specific styles from style attribute of **the Element and all Childrens of it**. I know that it should be recursive.

For example I have:

`<a href="" style="top:10px;left:4px;margin:4px"><img style="top:3px"/></a>`

And I remove `top` style. It converts to:

`<a href="" style="left:4px;margin:4px"><img style=""/></a>`

Comment: Nice. What's the problem, and where's your code?

Answer (score 1):

Use the function below for the parent node:

```
 private function prevent_html_style_properties($element){
    if($element->nodeType != XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
        return $element;
    $element->removeAttribute('class');
    if($element->hasAttribute('style')){
        $style = $element->getAttribute('style');
        $existingDeleteAttrList = array();
        $attrList = [
            'height',
            'position',
            'top'];
        $style_parts = explode(';', $style);
        foreach($attrList as $attr){
            if(strpos($style, $attr) !== false)
                $existingDeleteAttrList[] = $attr;
        }
        $new_attr_value = '';
        foreach($style_parts as $style_part){
            $attr_is_safe = true;
            foreach($existingDeleteAttrList as $attr){
                if(strpos($style_part, $attr) !== false) {
                    $attr_is_safe = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if($attr_is_safe)
                $new_attr_value .= $style_part . ';';
        }
        $element->setAttribute('style', $new_attr_value);
    }

    $children  = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($children as $child)
    {
        $element->replaceChild($this->prevent_html_tag_styles($child), $child);
    }
    return $element;
}
```

Usage:

```
 $element = $this->prevent_html_style_properties($element);
```

Some Explanation:

- Some children are simple text and do not have any attributes. So we had to check if it is `XML_ELEMENT_NODE`.
- It uses `replaceChild` to fix for its direct children, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code using JQUERY

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('a *').css('top',''); // For Remove specific property of child element

$('a').css('top',''); // For Remove specific property of element
});
```